# How to create custom toString method of an object

Tags: javascript

I want to create a custom `toString()`method of the following `a` object. But I am unable to do so. I read the I should override the `prototype.toString` but I am getting compilation error

```
 var a = {
    someProperty: 1,
    someotherProperty:3
}

a.prototype.toString = function customPrint(){
    return "the custom print is "+(someProperty+someotherProperty);
}

var b = {
    somePropertyb: 2
}

function printObject(){
    console.log("using , hello: a:",a,"b:",b); //prints using , hello: a: { someProperty: 1, someotherProperty: 3 } b: { somePropertyb: 2 }
    console.log("using + hello: a:"+a+"b:"+b);//prints using + hello: a:[object Object]b:[object Object] if I remove a.prototype.toString code
}

printObject()
```

The error I am getting is

`node print.js`
`print.js:6`
`a.prototype.toString = function customPrint(){`
                     `^`

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'toString' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\...\print.js:6:22)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` is not a class, so it doesn't have a `prototype` you can assign to like that. Instead, simply put the `toString` method on the object itself:

```js
var a = {
  someProperty: 1,
  someotherProperty: 3,
  toString: function() {
    return "the custom print is " + this.someProperty + this.someotherProperty;
  },
}


var b = {
  somePropertyb: 2
}

function printObject() {
  console.log("using + hello: a:" + a + "b:" + b);
}

printObject()
```